# JS TS how to refactor repetitive code into a higher order function with multiple param types

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring, higher-order-functions

I've been wanting to refactor the following code into a higher order function with typescript to make it cleaner and more re-usable, though have been finding it really challenging to make it work.

```
import { DocumentDefinition, FilterQuery, QueryOptions, UpdateQuery } from 'mongoose';
import TaskModel, { TaskDocument } from '../models/Task.model';
import { databaseResponseTimeHistogram } from '../utils/appmetrics';

export async function createTask(
    input: DocumentDefinition<
        Omit<TaskDocument, 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt' | 'taskId' | 'isCompleted'>
    >
) {
    const metricsLabels = { operation: 'createTask' };
    const timer = databaseResponseTimeHistogram.startTimer();

    try {
        const result = TaskModel.create(input);
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'true' });

        return result;
    } catch (err: any) {
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'false' });
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
}

export async function findTask(
    query: FilterQuery<TaskDocument>,
    options: QueryOptions = { lean: true }
) {
    const metricsLabels = { operation: 'findTask' };
    const timer = databaseResponseTimeHistogram.startTimer();

    try {
        const result = TaskModel.findOne(query, {}, options);
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'true' });

        return result;
    } catch (err: any) {
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'false' });
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
}

export async function findAndUpdateTask(
    query: FilterQuery<TaskDocument>,
    update: UpdateQuery<TaskDocument>,
    options: QueryOptions
) {
    const metricsLabels = { operation: 'findTask' };
    const timer = databaseResponseTimeHistogram.startTimer();

    try {
        const result = TaskModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'true' });

        return result;
    } catch (err: any) {
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'false' });
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
}
```

Basically I am wanting to refactor the whole metrics functionality with the try catch block into a utility function, allowing to call it with the respective parameters, the operation, the TaskModel.method and corresponding params with would be (input) for create, (query, {}, options) for findOne and (query, update, options) for findManyAndUpdate...

So far have I ran into difficulties with correct typing of all the different params etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to refactor this part:

```
try {
    /* SOME OPERATION */
    timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'true' });

    return result;
} catch (err: any) {
    timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'false' });
    throw new Error(err.message);
}
```

You can just wrap it in a function and pass in the `SOME OPERATION` as an argument:

```
function withTimer (label:string, operation:Function) {
    const metricsLabels = { operation: label };
    const timer = databaseResponseTimeHistogram.startTimer();

    try {
        const result = operation();
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'true' });

        return result;
    } catch (err: any) {
        timer({ ...metricsLabels, success: 'false' });
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
}
```

Now your functions can be rewritten as:

```
export async function createTask(
    input: DocumentDefinition<
        Omit<TaskDocument, 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt' | 'taskId' | 'isCompleted'>
    >
) {
    return withTimer('createTask',
        () => TaskModel.create(input)
    );
}

export async function findTask(
    query: FilterQuery<TaskDocument>,
    options: QueryOptions = { lean: true }
) {
    return withTimer('findTask',
        () => TaskModel.findOne(query, {}, options)
    );
}

export async function findAndUpdateTask(
    query: FilterQuery<TaskDocument>,
    update: UpdateQuery<TaskDocument>,
    options: QueryOptions
) {
    return withTimer('findTask',
        () => TaskModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    );
}
```

The key to using higher-order functions is realizing that you can wrap the **uncommon** parts of code in functions to be passed to the common parts of code.

Comment: Thank you slebetman, great input! So simple, I realize I unnecessarily complicated things. One more thing that I am trying to wrap my head around is how to make this type secure. I have some tests running and it broke with this implementation, but just because of typescript. So what I did is: `export type metricLabelsService = 'createTask' | 'findTask';

export function withTimer(label: metricLabelsService, operation: any) {` Best case I'd really like to get rid of the any type, so I tried to assert a function as a type () => {} but that didn't quite work.

Comment: Personally I'd just put `string` as the type of `label`. Initially you can do `function withTimer(label:string, operation: Function) ...`. This ensures that you need to pass a function as the `operation`. If you know the return type (and the return type is fixed) you can do `function withTimer(label:string, operation: () => ReturnType) ...`. I'm not sure what the return type of `TaskModel.xxx()` is